# how to iterate a map with key as custom wrapper class reference on visual force page

Tags: visualforce, map, list, wrapper-class

my map is

```
public Map<wrapmapdetails,List<SCQLWrapperClass>>map_lineitems_Group_List123{get;set;}
```

and its corresponding wrapper class

```
public class wrapmapdetails
{
public String yearname{get;set;}
public Double pricepermonth{get;set;}
public Double netpricepermonth{get;set;}
public Double billingtotal{get;set;}

wrapmapdetails()
{

}
}
```

the visual force code

```
<apex:repeat value="{!map_lineitems_Group_List123}" var="i" >
here my code will come to parse the map and dispay as a table
</apex:repeat>
```

but i was getting

> Visualforce Error This map cannot be used in an iteration because the
>   keys cannot be sorted

Answer (score 1):

With this controller:

```
public class MyController {
    public class wrapmapdetails {
        public String yearname{get;set;}
        public Double pricepermonth{get;set;}
        public Double netpricepermonth{get;set;}
        public Double billingtotal{get;set;}
        wrapmapdetails() {
        }
    } 
    public Map<wrapmapdetails, List<Object>> map_lineitems_Group_List123 {get;set;}
    public MyController() {
        map_lineitems_Group_List123 = new Map<wrapmapdetails, List<Object>>();
    }
}
```

and this page:

```
<apex:page controller="MyController">
    <apex:repeat value="{!map_lineitems_Group_List123}" var="i">
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

I get neither a compile time or runtime error like the one you report including when I set the API version right back to 15. Perhaps the problem lies elsewhere in your page?

Not the cause of your problem, but when using a custom class as a map key or in sets, you are likely to get unexpected results unless you appropriately define both an `equals` and a `hashCode` method. See [Using Custom Types in Map Keys and Sets](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_collections_maps_keys_userdefined.htm).

Comment: might be error was from other part of the code....Due to some restrictions i haven't posted complete code...   Will check and let you know...

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you need to change your Key field datatype in your Map variable. It should be a primitive datatype.

[Referencing Apex Maps and Lists](https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_maps_lists.htm)

Comment: yaa i understand but i have to display this wrapper class values too , so i have taken key as a custom data type.... i come across something we can use custom data types to but have to implement sorting functionality....

Comment: yes, apex comparable interface will allow custom sorting in your wrapper class - [Comparable Interface](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_comparable.htm)

Comment: i have done custom sorting but it is giving same error....

Comment: in that case I think you have your options limited. You should then split your logic into using Multiple Map variables, one map variable for usage in VF page in repeat tag, while other variable for your calculations purposes in APEX. Core of the issue is, there might be issues in using a custom wrapper class as KeySet for map, since for VF collections, if it isn't a primitive datatype, then there is no way for vf to know which particular property variable of wrapper class to use. And that seems to be a necessity for saving the page code.